# HTML/CSS table with equal-width columns that automatically fit all content

Tags: html, css

I want every column to have the same width, but I want the column width to be wide enough to fit all of the cell content without wrapping (i.e. equal to the width of the content of the widest cell in the table).

So if the three rows are:

```
9|9|9
9|9|9
9|9|9
```

... and each digit is 10 pixels I would want each column to be ~10 pixels.

But if the three rows are:

```
9|9|999999999999
9|9|9
9|9|9
```

... and one of the columns is 120 pixels wide, I would want each column to be ~120 pixels.

Note: the solution must also not make assumptions about the number of rows/columns in the table, because these tables are being generated dynamically and can be of arbitrary dimension.

Answer (score -1):

Try Bootstrap 4. Name each div class in .row as .col
Your divs will all have equal width and will be set with same width.

eg.

<div class="row"> 
   <div class="col"> col 1 </div> 
   <div class="col"> col 2 </div> 
</div>

Comment: Thanks. I will look into this as a last resort, but I was hoping to avoid having bootstrap as a dependency.